# Is this a known issue - Inactive Picklist Value shows up on a new Order

Tags: picklist, opportunity, quote, order, in-active-picklist-values

I have an inactive picklist on the OrderType field on Order.

When I create a new Order record from an existing Quote record, then the Order after creation shows 'New'  as an Option in the OrderType picklist

However, when i create a new Quote for an existing Opportunity, then create a new Order for that Quote, then the Order after creation does  not show 'New'  as an Option in the OrderType picklist.

I know this -  Records created before making a Picklist value inactive will show on the record.

But I don't know why a new Order created from the related list of the existing Quote
should surface an inactive value ?

Does anyone know if this is a known issue ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: look at any automation (esp apex) that might be setting this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue

This is a Standard behavior of OOB CPQ.
CPQ automatically gives the 'Order Type' a value based on the type of Order generated.

When a new order gets generated, the Order Type is 'New'. If the Order is generated due to renewal, then the Order Type is 'Renewal'.